# Groupby categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame similar to this:

```
name     Gender    Country
John       1        US
Kingsley   1        US
Smith      0        UK
Lily       0        UK
Elizabeth  0        US
Elizabeth  1        US 
Lily       1        UK 
Smith      0        US
```

I am hoping to print two lists:

1. Same Name, Different Gender e.g.
   Elizabeth 0
   Elizabeth 1
2. Same Name, Different Country e.g.
   Smith US
   Smith UK

I am using

```
df.groupby('name')['gender']
```

however, I wasn't able to get the list that I wanted, such as

```
df1
Elizabeth 0
Elizabeth 1
Lily 0 
Lily 1
```

Is there anyway to solve the code problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) with [`nunqiue`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html)

```
s = df[df.groupby('name').Gender.transform('nunique').gt(1)]
Out[53]: 
        name  Gender Country
3       Lily       0      UK
4  Elizabeth       0      US
5  Elizabeth       1      US
6       Lily       1      UK
```

For 2nd part use the same logic as above

```py
df[df.groupby('name').Country.transform('nunique').gt(1)]
    name  Gender Country
2  Smith       0      UK
7  Smith       0      US
```

Comment: Edited the answer to add links and 2nd part. If not ok feel free to revert the changes.